# How to get the default field values that will be in the form beforehand in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, default-value, odoo

I have some form views similar to `account.voucher.receipt.dialog.form` which is in the file:
 `/addons_path/account_voucher/voucher_payment_receipt_view.xml`.

- Some `field` tags get their default values which were defined in the Model,
- Some `field` tags get their default values from on change methods (defined by `on_change` attributes).

I want to bypass these form views and automate the process, so I need to know in advance these default field values. 
In that way, I only need to add additional field values if needed, then call the `create` method on the model.

I'm using Odoo v8.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print in the log all the default values of your model you can do this:

```
from inspect import isfunction

@api.multi
def get_default_fields(self):
    for key, value in self._fields.iteritems():
        if value.name not in models.MAGIC_COLUMNS:
            if self._defaults.get(value.name, False):
                if isfunction(self._defaults[value.name]):
                    _logger.debug(self._defaults[value.name](
                        self, self.env.cr, self.env.uid, None
                    ))
                else:
                    _logger.debug(self._defaults[value.name])
```

I think you can adapt this code to your needs.

And if you want get the value of one field assigned by an `onchange` method maybe you have to run the method manually